# Is there anyway to find out if there any undefined steps in my .feature files?

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

I can go to the feature file in cucumber and see each step and I will know which ones are defined and which ones aren't.
However, is there a way that I can see whethere there are any undefined steps in .feature files in my entire project.

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine 2020.1 and later allows running the **Undefined step** [inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/running-inspections.html#run-one-inspection) for the entire project to find undefined steps:

1. From the main menu, select **Code | Run Inspection by Name**.
2. Type *Undefined step* in the popup and press **Enter**.
3. Make sure that **Whole project** is selected and click **OK** to find undefined steps.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your cucumber, the console will show you all unimplemented scenario statement and suggest you to implement it.

Also, In java cucumber plug-in the .feature file statement are not implement shown in yellow color. it may same in ruby too